# Dark Mode with button in Vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript

So basically, I am having troubles with a button that is supposed to change a website to dark mode. I also have a night mode, which makes the website go dark according to being after sunset or before sunrise in the current place of the user, and this night mode works. So I know it must be a problem regarding my js...

I have already tried first adding lightMode and then removing darkMode, but it did not work either...

```html
      <button
              type="button"
              class="btn btn-outline-secondary"
              id="buttonChangeMode"
            >
              <i class="far fa-moon"></i>
            </button>
```

```css
.lightMode .app {
  border: 1px solid #0b0b35;
  padding: 20px 15px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  max-height: 2500px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}
.darkMode .app {
  border: 1px solid #0b0b35;
  padding: 20px 15px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  max-height: 2500px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(7, 8, 14);
}
```

```js
function changeMode() {
  let mode = document.getElementById("body");
  if (mode.classList.contains("lightMode")) {
    mode.classList.add("darkMode").remove("lightMode");
  } else if (mode.classList.contains("lightMode")) {
    mode.classList.remove("darkMode").add("lightMode");
  }
}

let buttonChangeMode = document.querySelector("#buttonChangeMode");
buttonChangeMode.addEventListener("click", changeMode);
```

In the console, the error presented is: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined
    at HTMLButtonElement.changeMode"

Comment: [ClassList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)'s methods do not support chaining. There is, however, [workaround for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28653761/chaining-html5-classlist-api-without-jquery).

Comment: remove() is a method. You can‘t use the method remove on function add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.toggle()` method of `.classList` is the easiest way. If you use id you only limit your code use class whenever possible. Details are commented in demo.

```js
// Pass Event Object
function changeMode(event) {
  // Event.target always points to what user clicked, hovered over, changed etc,
  const clicked = event.target;
  // Reference body.all
  const all = document.querySelector('.all');

  // If the clicked tag has .mode class...
  if (clicked.matches('.mode')) {
    // Toggle .fa-sun, .btn-outline-dark, ,btn-outline-light, and .fa-moon on button.mode
    clicked.classList.toggle('fa-moon');
    clicked.classList.toggle('btn-outline-dark');
    clicked.classList.toggle('fa-sun');
    clicked.classList.toggle('btn-outline-light');
    // Toggle .darkMode and .lightMode on body.all
    all.classList.toggle('darkMode');
    all.classList.toggle('lightMode');
  }
  return false;
}

// Reference button.mode
const mode = document.querySelector(".mode");

// Register button.mode to the click event
mode.addEventListener("click", changeMode);
```

```css
.lightMode .app {
  border: 1px solid #0b0b35;
  padding: 20px 15px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  max-height: 2500px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}

.darkMode .app {
  border: 1px solid #0b0b35;
  padding: 20px 15px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  max-height: 2500px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(7, 8, 14);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.9.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body class='all lightMode'>
  <main class='app container'>
    <section class='row'>
      <article class='col-6'>
        <button class="mode btn btn-outline-dark far fa-sun" type="button"></button>
      </article>
      <figure class='col-6'>
        <img src='https://branditprintit.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/logo-degin-logo-design-design-art-free.png' style='width:80%'>
      </figure>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not give a HTML snippet - If your HTML `<body>` tag does not have an ID as follows:

```
<html>
...
    <body id="body">
...
```

you will get that error because the result of the `let mode = document.getElementById("body");` statement will be undefined, because the getElementById() function is expecting an argument of a DOM element ID value.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Answer (score 0):

You should add / remove classes like that:

```
<script>
function changeMode() {
  let mode = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]; // set a variable for body tag
  if (mode.classList.contains("lightMode")) {
    mode.classList.add("darkMode")
    mode.classList.remove("lightMode");
  } 
  else {
    mode.classList.add("lightMode")
    mode.classList.remove("darkMode");
  }
}

let buttonChangeMode = document.querySelector("#buttonChangeMode");
buttonChangeMode.addEventListener("click", changeMode);
</script>
```

You can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)