# Change a few code format (angularJS to javascript)

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, format

I'm learning javascript and AngularJS. I made this little code for something (we made it in AngularJS format), and we need to make this same logic but using only javascript.

The color of a botton changes to other when it's available or unavailable.

Can someone help me with this and tell me the logic?

```
$scope.saveButton= function(){
  $( "#saveButtonPics" ).removeClass( "attachment-space-available" ).addClass( "attachment-boton-guardado" );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not Angular but jQuery apart from the $scope which I guess is part of some Angular scope

A plain JS version could be

```
const saveButton = () => { 
  const cl = document.getElementById("saveButtonPics").classList;
  cl.remove("attachment-space-available")
  cl.add("attachment-boton-guardado");
};
```

If you want to chain, have a look at [chaining HTML5 classList API without (Jquery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28653761/chaining-html5-classlist-api-without-jquery)

```
const classList = elt => {
  const list = elt.classList;
  return {
    toggle: function(c) { list.toggle(c); return this; },
    add:    function(c) { list.add   (c); return this; },
    remove: function(c) { list.remove(c); return this; }
  };
};

const saveButton = () { 
  classList(document.getElementById("saveButtonPics"))
    .remove("attachment-space-available")
    .add("attachment-boton-guardado");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In angularjs we need change model to change view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">


<button ng-click="saveButton()" ng-class="savebtnclass">Save Pics</button>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.savebtnclass = "attachment-space-available";
    $scope.saveButton=function(){
        $scope.savebtnclass = "attachment-boton-guardado";
    }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But the question was how to do this in Vanilla JS